# pyodbc too few parameters using a multifield value as WHERE condition

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

i have this code

`cursor.execute(f'''SELECT {Data[0]} FROM {Data[1]} WHERE PersonalInfo.hook.Value = 16''')`

but when i execute the code i get the error:

`pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')`

the hook is a multivalued field and Data is a tuple that shows where i want the data from containing the table and the field name.

but when i delete the WHERE part it runs fine.

Comment: You should print your f-string query, it should contain a `?`, that's your parameter. **PS**. templating for SQL queries is dangerous as it opens the door to SQL injection, make sure you absolutely control what is in `Data`.

Comment: Why is the table name in the `FROM` part from a tuple, but static in the `WHERE` part?